# Unable to spot React element with missing "key" property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using SingleSpa, React and MUI. I get the following warning in the Browser console but am unable to find the element that is missing the "key" prop.

I'm a bit lost as I do not know what this "pn" element might be. There is also other similar warnings in the Browser console, also naming component names I do not know. This only happens with production builds, but not in development mode. I guess the funky two-letter component names are obfuscated, but as the bug does not occur in development mode I cannot find the actual component names in order to locate the problem.

I do not have arrays where I create same sibling elements without a key, but what I do have are similar components (such as Tooltip components) sitting next to each other, with their order and number being fixed, but them being shown and hidden dynamically (by conditional rendering). I've tried to add "key" properties to those components as well, but that did not seem to help. (Or maybe it did help, but there are more such instances which I cannot spot.)

Example message:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. 
    in pn (created by ForwardRef)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by Styled(input))
    in Styled(input) (created by ForwardRef)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by Wc)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by Wc)
    in Wc (created by ig)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ec)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ec)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ec)
    in header (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ec)
    in div (created by Styled(div))
    in Styled(div) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ec)
    in ec (created by ig)
    in ig (created by rootComponent)
    in lo (created by rootComponent)
    in co (created by xo)
    in xo (created by rootComponent)
    in Wr (created by Hr)
    in $r (created by Hr)
    in Hr (created by rootComponent)
    in rootComponent
    in SingleSpaReactErrorBoundary(@mesalvo/mesalvo-mf-diagnosticreport)
    in SingleSpaRoot(@mesalvo/mesalvo-mf-diagnosticreport)
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**:

1. Thanks for the pointer to the React Dev Tools. I installed, tried - was really helpful:

[image: React DevTools screenshot]

2. Source code snipped (of the "Ga" component identified by the Dev Tools):

```
      return (
        <AppBar component="div" position="sticky" elevation={0}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="center">
              <Grid item>
                <Tooltip title="Modulauswahl">
                  <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={openLeftDrawer} edge="start">
                    <MenuIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs>
                <Routes>
                  <Route
                    path="/:appPath/:profileId/patient/*"
                    element={<PatientContextHeader patient={context.patient} />}
                  />
                <!-- ... more Route elements ... -->
                </Routes>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Tooltip title="Hilfe">
                  <IconButton color="inherit">
                    <HelpIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Tooltip title="Administration">
                  <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    onClick={() => {
                      window.location.replace("/admin/");
                    }}
                  >
                    <SettingsIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Tooltip title="Dark Mode">
                  <IconButton color="inherit">
                    <Brightness4Icon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <ProfileMenu context={context} profileService={profileService} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <UserMenu />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Tooltip title="Objektauswahl">
                  <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={openRightDrawer} edge="end">
                    <MenuIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
```

Comment: You can use the React devtools' inspector to find an element whose mangled name is `pn`, then figure out things from there.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of your problem please